# Obtain the JPanel/ Componenets residing over a glasspane

Tags: java, swing

How do I obtain the `JPanel` that resides over the Glasspane of my `JFrame`? I am very new to Java and stackoverflow pardon me if this is a repeated question.

I have a panel as `frame.setGlassPane(glassPanel);` and I have to copy that glasspanel object into a temp `JPanel` variable called `tempGlassPanel`  I am doing this because I have another `JPanel` that I wanna add momentarily over the glassPane and swap back this `glassPanel` later on. This is an API design so I don't have direct access to `glassPanel` I could only access by doing something like `frame.getGlassPane()` or something like that.

Thanks

Comment: See the demos [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html).

Comment: I looked at this but I don't understand which example you r specifying at ? Could you be more specific ?

Comment: All of them, but [`GlassPaneDemo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html#eg) shows how to detect clicks on underlying components.

Comment: `frame.getGlassPane()`?

Comment: Thank you trashgod and MadProgrammer . I got it working by using the GlassPaneDemo